# rails3-jquery-autocomplete passing parameter to scope query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm struggling to find an answer to a problem I have with the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem.

I have 2 models. Environment & Property.

```
class Environment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties

 name: string, envfile: string

class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_environment_id, where(:environment_id => 14)  
  belongs_to :environment 

name: string, value: string, environment_id: integer
```

I have a view which displays all the properties belonging to a particular environment and in that view the following code which auto searches based on the property name

```
<%= form_tag('tbd')%>
  <%= autocomplete_field_tag :property_name, '', autocomplete_property_name_properties_path>
```

The properties controller

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :property, :name, :scopes => [:with_environment_id]
```

and routes.rb has

```
  get :autocomplete_property_name, :on => :collection
```

The autocomplete works fine but it returns returns all records in properties table. Where I would like only the properties belonging to the environment displayed in the view.

As you can see I've defined a scope in the property model in which I've hardcoded a valid environment_id to make this work as I would want it.

So my question is how do I pass the environment_id from the view/controller back into the scope?

Perhaps I'm tackling this from the wrong angle.

Apologies if it's a dumb question but it has stumped me all day.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_autocomplete_items(parameters)
  super(parameters).where(:user_id => current_user.id)
end
```